# Recursion return wrong list of lists

Tags: python, list, recursion

I try to solve a problem and one part of it is to find all paths from (0, 0) to the right most point of the 2d array. This is my code:

```
def route_finder_helper(x, y, current_path, filler, list_of_lists):

    current_path[filler] = (x, y)

    if x == 0 and y == 0:
        print(current_path)
        list_of_lists.append(current_path)
        return list_of_lists

    if x == 0:
        return route_finder_helper(x, y - 1, current_path, filler - 1, list_of_lists)

    if y == 0:
        return route_finder_helper(x - 1, y, current_path, filler - 1, list_of_lists)

    return route_finder_helper(x-1, y, current_path, filler - 1, list_of_lists) + \
           route_finder_helper(x, y-1, current_path, filler - 1, list_of_lists)
```

where x and y is current coordinate, current_path is a list of tuples of the current path, filler is index what position of the list to change and list_of_lists should be all the paths. However, when I run this program and print the return value I get this output:

```
 [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2)]
 [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2)]
 [(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2)]
 [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
 [(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
 [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
 [[(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]]
```

So I get the correct paths, but I do not know how to save them to the list of lists. Could someone help me?

This is how I call my function:

```
x_coordinate = coordinates[0]  
y_coordinate = coordinates[1]  
path_length = (x_coordinate + 1) + (y_coordinate + 1) - 1  
start_filling = path_length - 1  
current_path = [0] * path_length  
paths = route_finder_helper(x_coordinate, y_coordinate, current_path, 
start_filling, [])
```

This is what it should return:

```
[[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2)],[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]]
```

Comment: Can you provide an example on how you call the function? What is wrong with the current output? I guess the last one (the list of lists) shouldn't be there?

Comment: x_coordinate = coordinates[0]; 
y_coordinate = coordinates[1];   
path_length = (x_coordinate + 1) + (y_coordinate + 1) - 1;    
start_filling = path_length - 1;    
current_path = [0] * path_length;    
paths = route_finder_helper(x_coordinate, y_coordinate, current_path, start_filling, [])

Comment: I cannot put it in newline, but I hope you will see

Comment: Yes I understand, best would be to edit the question and add it there, but its fine for now. I'm going to bed soon, I might not have time to 'solve' this one tonight.

Comment: thanks for editing the question. I changed my answer, I think I solved it :)

Comment: What is the `coordinates` variable you refer to in the sample code where you call your function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the corrected answer:

```
def route_finder_helper(x, y, current_path, filler, list_of_lists):

    current_path[filler] = (x, y)

    if x == 0 and y == 0:
        return list_of_lists + [current_path[:]]

    if x == 0:
        return route_finder_helper(x, y - 1, current_path, filler - 1, list_of_lists)

    if y == 0:
        return route_finder_helper(x - 1, y, current_path, filler - 1, list_of_lists)

    return route_finder_helper(x-1, y, current_path, filler - 1, list_of_lists) + \
           route_finder_helper(x, y-1, current_path, filler - 1, list_of_lists)

x_coordinate = 2
y_coordinate = 2
path_length = (x_coordinate + 1) + (y_coordinate + 1) - 1
start_filling = path_length - 1
current_path = [0] * path_length
paths = route_finder_helper(x_coordinate, y_coordinate, current_path, start_filling, [])
print(paths)
```

Output:

```
[[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2)], 
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2)], 
[(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2)], 
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2)], 
[(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2)], 
[(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]]
```

The correction here is:

```
return list_of_lists + [current_path[:]]
```

where I add a *copy* by using `current_path[:]`

Answer (score 1):

The logic of the code is correct, the problem that you have is that you are dealing with a list which is a mutable item. This means that every variable which has a reference to the list, gets an updated list when you change it for only one variable:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a
a[0] = -1
print(b)
>>> [-1, 2, 3]
```

Something like this also happens in your code when you append to the `list_of_lists`. Simply changing the append to this:

```
# return list_of_lists.append(current_path)  <- old code
return list_of_lists + [current_path]  <- new code
```

This guarantees that you start a new list every time the code ends up there, instead of appending to a list where other parts of the code have a reference to as well.

If this is a new concept for you in Python there are plenty of nice blogs which explain this in more detail than me, e.g. [here](https://medium.com/@meghamohan/mutable-and-immutable-side-of-python-c2145cf72747)

**complete code:**

```
def route_finder_helper(x, y, current_path, filler, list_of_lists):

    current_path[filler] = (x, y)

    if x == 0 and y == 0:
        return list_of_lists + [current_path]

    if x == 0:
        return route_finder_helper(x, y - 1, current_path, filler - 1, list_of_lists)

    if y == 0:
        return route_finder_helper(x - 1, y, current_path, filler - 1, list_of_lists)

    return route_finder_helper(x-1, y, current_path, filler - 1, list_of_lists) + \
           route_finder_helper(x, y-1, current_path, filler - 1, list_of_lists)

x_coordinate = 2
y_coordinate = 2
path_length = (x_coordinate + 1) + (y_coordinate + 1) - 1
start_filling = path_length - 1
current_path = [0] * path_length
paths = route_finder_helper(x_coordinate, y_coordinate, current_path, start_filling, [])
print(paths)
>>> [[(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]]
```

Comment: No, this is not correct.  I need to save every path as a list of tuples and once goal point is reached (2,2) in this case, I need to add it to the list of all paths, but after recursion that list gets corrupted.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. However, when I run it, it still returns the same list.

Comment: @Augustas, are you sure? I checked again on my pc and it works. I added the 'complete' code

Comment: Thats very interesting. I will try again in the evening. Thanks very much

Comment: Your output that you show is a list of identical lists. Compare this to the required output that the OP states at the end of the question.

Comment: I checked again. The list which I need to get and which you posted is not the same.

Comment: Ah yeah my bad, I just checked whether the length was correct. I guess @quamrana's solution is correct by also a copy of current_path