# How to return a new list of lists in python correctly

Tags: python, list, recursion, reference

I try to solve a problem and one part of it is to find all paths from (0, 0) to the right most point of the 2d array. This is my code:

```
def route_finder_helper(x, y, current_path, filler, list_of_lists):

    current_path[filler] = (x, y)

    if x == 0 and y == 0:
        print(current_path)
        list_of_lists.append(current_path)
        return list_of_lists

    if x == 0:
        return route_finder_helper(x, y - 1, current_path, filler - 1, list_of_lists)

    if y == 0:
        return route_finder_helper(x - 1, y, current_path, filler - 1, list_of_lists)

    return route_finder_helper(x-1, y, current_path, filler - 1, list_of_lists) + \
           route_finder_helper(x, y-1, current_path, filler - 1, list_of_lists)
```

where x and y is current coordinate, current_path is a list of tuples of the current path, filler is index what position of the list to change and list_of_lists should be all the paths. However, when I run this program and print the return value I get this output:

```
 [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2)]
 [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2)]
 [(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2)]
 [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
 [(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
 [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
 [[(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]]
```

So I get the correct paths, but I do not know how to save them to the list of lists. Could someone help me?

This is how I call my function:

```
x_coordinate = coordinates[0]  
y_coordinate = coordinates[1]  
path_length = (x_coordinate + 1) + (y_coordinate + 1) - 1  
start_filling = path_length - 1  
current_path = [0] * path_length  
paths = route_finder_helper(x_coordinate, y_coordinate, current_path, 
start_filling, [])
```

This is what it should return:

```
[[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2)],[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]]
```

Comment: You are reusing the same object.

Comment: You've asked this question before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58582843/recursion-return-wrong-list-of-lists

Comment: Yes, but the answer is not correct. It still returns the same thing.

Comment: Did the edit from @Maarten-vd-Sande an hour ago make any difference?

Comment: When i ran it, it returned the same wrong list.